# How to color table cell groups of equal elements

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, cell

For an HTML table with numbers, I am looking for an elegant JavaScript/CSS way to identify groups of equal values in each column, and color the background of corresponding cells accordingly. I will use it in a web presentation of regression test results.

In python I would probably have used something like itertools.groupby().

To illustrate, I include a screenshot example and the corresponding HTML code (constructed manually).

```html
<head>
  <style>
    td {font-family: Monospace; font-size:16; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table border=1>
    <tr><td>1.111</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1.111</td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor="LightBlue">2.222</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1.111</td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor="LightBlue">2.222</td></tr>
    <tr><td> 1.111</td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor="LightBlue">2.222</td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor="Goldenrod">3.333</td></tr>
    <tr><td> 1.111</td></tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?  Are you using a library or are you writing vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: Initially I imagined writing my own little JavaScript function... I am not familiar with jQuery. I could probably be persuaded to use it if it provides something simple?

Comment: Create an empty object. Iterate over the `<td>` elements, checking the text contents. For each, if the contents are not present as a property in the object, add the contents as a property and allocate a color to it. When you find cell text, use that existing color, else use the new color. How you allocate colors is up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pure JavaScript solution (with [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QN8hw/1/)) that works on your posted sample source:

```
function colorTableCells() {
    'use strict';
    var i = 0; //counter variable
    var j = 0; //counter variable
    var k = 0; //counter variable
    var m = 0; //counter variable
    var n = 0; //counter variable
    var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table'); //All tables as a collection.
    var rows = []; //table rows collection, needed to determine columns
    var cells = []; //td collection
    var cell = {}; //used first as a Cell object (custom, see below) and then as a td (after all unique values by column have been determined
    var values = []; //array of Cell objects (custom, see below).
    var columnColorMap = {
        'column0': 'gray',
        'column1': 'purple',
        'column2': 'pink',
        'column3': 'mint',
        'column4': 'cyan'
    }; //columnColorMap holds the shade with which to color the column.
    var C = function () {
        //Cell Object, holds properties unique to the cells for coloring
        this.value = 0; //Cell value
        this.color = {
            'red': 255,
            'green': 255,
            'blue': 255
        }; //Cell color, determined by column
        this.shades = {
            'gray': [this.color.red, this.color.green, this.color.blue],
            'purple': [this.color.red, this.color.green],
            'pink': [null, this.color.green, this.color.blue],
            'mint': [this.color.red, , this.color.blue],
            'cyan': [this.color.red],
            'magenta': [null, this.color.green],
            'yellow': [null, null, this.color.blue]
        }; //A quick way to determine the shade for the column. It holds color values to modify (and always in RGB order) or a null value if R, G, or B should be left alone.
        this.column = 0; //Column the cell is in, relative to the table it is in.
        this.darken = function (stepValue, hue) {
            //function that returns a new color, based on the hue that is passed in
            var decrement = 8;
            var i = 0;
            var ret = {
                'red': 255,
                'green': 255,
                'blue': 255
            };
            if (!stepValue) {
                stepValue = 0;
            }
            decrement = decrement * stepValue;
            for (i = 0; i < hue.length; i += 1) {
                if (hue[i]) {
                    hue[i] = hue[i] - decrement;
                }
            }
            if (hue[0]) {
                ret.red = hue[0];
            }
            if (hue[1]) {
                ret.green = hue[1];
            }
            if (hue[2]) {
                ret.blue = hue[2];
            }
            return ret;
        };
        this.getHexBackgroundColorString = function () {
            //returns `rbg(val, val, val) as '#RRGGBB'
            var s = '';
            var red = this.color.red.toString(16);
            var green = this.color.green.toString(16);
            var blue = this.color.blue.toString(16);
            if (red.length < 2) {
                red = '0' + red;
            }
            if (green.length < 2) {
                green = '0' + green;
            }
            if (green.length < 2) {
                blue = '0' + blue;
            }
            s = '#' + red + green + blue;
            return s.toUpperCase();
        };
    };
    var colHasValue = function (array, cell) {
        //loop through array, returns 'if cell.value && cell.column are found or otherwise'
        var i = 0;
        var found = false;
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
            if (array[i].value === cell.value && array[i].column === cell.column) {
                found = true;
                i = array.length;
            }
        }
        return found;
    };
    for (i = 0; i < tables.length; i += 1) {
        cells = tables[i].getElementsByTagName('td'); //get all td elements per table
        for (j = 0; j < cells.length; j += 1) {
            cell = new C(); //grab a new Cell object
            cell.value = parseFloat(cells[j].innerText); //capture cell value
            cell.column = cells[j].cellIndex; //capture cell column
            if (!colHasValue(values, cell)) {
                //hasn't been previously stored yet, so darken according to column and store
                cell.color = cell.darken(j, cell.shades[columnColorMap['column' + cell.column.toString()]]);
                values.push(cell); //capture all unique values
            }
        }
        rows = tables[i].getElementsByTagName('tr'); //grab all rows by table
        for (k = 0; k < rows.length; k += 1) {
            //start looping through all the rows
            for (m = 0; m < rows[k].childNodes.length; m += 1) {
                //start looping through all of the row's children
                if (rows[k].childNodes[m].nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'td') {
                    cell = rows[k].childNodes[m]; //found a td element, alias to cell for easier use
                    for (n = 0; n < values.length; n += 1) {
                        //loop through stored cell values
                        if (parseFloat(cell.innerText) === values[n].value && cell.cellIndex === values[n].column) {
                            //value and column matches
                            cell.style.backgroundColor = values[n].getHexBackgroundColorString(); //set background-color
                            n = values.length; //exit for
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
colorTableCells();
```

Modify any (or all) of the following to change the colors:

- The `shades` collection
- The `columnColorMap` object
- The `darken` function

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting. Like I have commented to jAndy above, it was probably not clear enough in my initial post that I need to limit the scope of equality to each column isolated from the rest, not the whole table. I mean only equal values **within one column** should have the same background color. How can I do that with your model?

Comment: Okay, modified to work via column and not arbitrary table data. Also, commented the source, fiddled more with coloring, and posted an updated jsFiddle. Updated post with new source and jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I could think of something like this

```
var lookup = Object.create( null );

Array.prototype.forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll('table td'), function( td ) {
    var id = td.textContent.trim();

    if( typeof lookup[ id ] === 'undefined' ) {
        lookup[ id ] = [ td ];
    }
    else {
        lookup[ id ].push( td );
    }
});

Object.keys( lookup ).forEach(function( name ) {
    if( lookup[ name ] && lookup[ name ].length ) {
        var rnd = 'rgba(red,green,blue,1)'
            .replace( 'red', ~~(Math.random() * 255) )
            .replace( 'green', ~~(Math.random() * 255) )
            .replace( 'blue', ~~(Math.random() * 255) );

        lookup[ name ].forEach(function( td ) {
            td.style.backgroundColor = rnd;
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ch6qZ/1/

A new words of caution: The above code heavily relies on ES5, so if you want to use it make sure you've also loaded an ES5-Shim library on your site for old'ish browsers. Also, the selector for `querySelectorAll` should be way more specific, best case scenario you can give that table an id. Lastly color generation happens per `Math.random()` in this example, you might want to define colors on your own.

---

This example code creates an empty object and uses it as a hash. Available `td` values are created once as keyname and the value for each key is an array of `td`'s which share the same text content. After that is done, we loop over that hash and set a random background-color for each `td`-group.

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting. I was probably not clear in my initial post, however in my case I need to limit the scope of equality to each column isolated from the rest, not the whole table. I mean only equal values **within one column** should have the same background color. I am not sure how to do that with your model?

Comment: @user1069609: I'm not entirely sure how you mean that, but you can modify the `querySelectorAll` selector to only select certain columns. for Instance `table td:nth-child(1)` will only affect the first column

Comment: How can I loop over all columns of a table with a given id? 

And a more general question: Can you point me to a good reference for the kind of JavaScript you have provided?

Answer (score 0):

you can with Jquery,

```
$("td:contains('2.222')").css("background-color","LightBlue");
$("td:contains('3.333')").css("background-color","Goldenrod");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that value is a decimal number, you can extract the color with the quotient divided by  % 10.

color choice function

```
    choiceColor (value) {
        let colors = ['red', 'pink', 'purple', 'indigo', 'blue', 'light-blue', 'cyan', 'teal', 'green', 'lime']
        return colors[value % 10]
    }
```